# Re-order an array by indexes with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array and I’m trying to re-order this array based on another array. The second array is an array of indexes (see below). I’m looking to build a clean function to take two arguments (an array and an array of indexes), and return the re-ordered array. I've tried to build this function and have an example below, however it's not returning what I'm expecting. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var before = ["T", "T", "A", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "A", "T", "T","T", "W", "W", "W", "W", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "W", "T"];
var indexes = [8, 2, 11, 22, 0, 4, 5, 18, 6, 17, 16, 19, 7, 3, 20, 1, 10, 9, 14, 13, 21, 12, 15];

// Attempt
function reorderArray(arrayToOrder ,order){
    // Get a copy of the array we want to change
    var temp = arrayToOrder
    // loop through the indexes
    // use the indexes to place the items in the right place from the copy into the original
    for(let i = 0; i < arrayToOrder.length; i++) {
        console.log("arr: ", arrayToOrder[order[i]] );
        console.log("temp: ", temp[i] );
        arrayToOrder[order[i]] = temp[i];
    }
    return arrayToOrder;
}
// run function
reorderArray( before, indexes );

// function should return this array
var after = ["A", "A", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W"];
```

Comment: Please note that copying reference of an object (arrays are also objects) doesn't create a copy. It actually create another reference to the same object.

Comment: are you sure about the result?

Comment: Your `after` looks like an alpha SORT not an index of the other array list.  Is this supposed to be a trick question :)

Comment: The question needs to be retitled, reworded, or corrected, The example code show how to reorder an array according to "rank", since it uses something like `arrayToOrder[rank[i]] = temp[i];` . If reordering an array according to "indexes", the key line of code is `arrayToOrder[i] = temp[index[i]];` . I don't know which case is more common, but one example of this is sorting an array of indexes 0 to length-1, according to another array, and in this case, the reorder is done according to indexes. You can convert indexes to rank : `rank[index[i]] = i;`  or vice versa `index[rank[i]] = i;` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map`

```js
var before = ["T", "T", "A", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "A", "T", "T","T", "W", "W", "W", "W", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "W", "T"];
var indexes = [8, 2, 11, 22, 0, 4, 5, 18, 6, 17, 16, 19, 7, 3, 20, 1, 10, 9, 14, 13, 21, 12, 15];

var output = indexes.map(i => before[i]);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for,Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the `indexes` with `Array.map()`, and return the value from the `before` array:

```js
const before = ["T", "T", "A", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "A", "T", "T","T", "W", "W", "W", "W", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "W", "T"];
const indexes = [8, 2, 11, 22, 0, 4, 5, 18, 6, 17, 16, 19, 7, 3, 20, 1, 10, 9, 14, 13, 21, 12, 15];

const reorderByIndexes = (arr, order) => order.map((index) => arr[index]);
  
const after = reorderByIndexes(before, indexes);

console.log(after.join());
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with a forEach if you don't want to use ES6

```js
var before = ["T", "T", "A", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "A", "T", "T", "T", "W", "W", "W", "W", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "W", "T"];
var indexes = [8, 2, 11, 22, 0, 4, 5, 18, 6, 17, 16, 19, 7, 3, 20, 1, 10, 9, 14, 13, 21, 12, 15];
var after = [];
indexes.forEach(function(value, index) {
  after[index] = before[value]
})

console.log(after)
```